# Add custom multiline HTML content to MatCell in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I would like to add multilines with different styles to my table cells. The Angular Material table seems to strip my HTML code away though. How can I achieve something similar like in [Gitlab](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/gitlab-users.png)  where the first line (e.g. "Administrator") inside one row/item is styled different as the second one (e.g. email-address) as shown in the code example.

### table-component.html

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{header}}</mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">

      <!-- first approach -->
      <div class="firstline">{{row.firstline}}</div>
      <div class="secondline">{{row.secondline}}</div>

      <!-- second approach -->
      <multiline-component [firstline]="row.firstline" [secondline]="row.secondline"></multiline-component>

   </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

### multiline-component.html

```html
<div class="firstline">{{firstline}}</div> // I want to be bold
<div class="secondline">{{secondline}}</div> // I want to be just regular
```

I have tried to use the [innerHTML] with a bypassSecurityTrustHtml()-Pipe to prevent the stripping without success. Also I have tried to use a custom component with [firstline] and [secondline] property bindings.

Comment: not clear what you're trying to achieve. first row in gitLab looks the same as the second, except different tags / funcitons available

Comment: By multline I mean multiple lines inside one row/item. In the GitLab example the first line would be "Administrator" and the second line the regarding email-address.

Comment: gotcha. what angular / material version are you on? your syntax looks pretty out dated

Comment: "@angular/core": "7.2.15", "@angular/material": "7.3.7"

Comment: I’d just check the material docs. Your syntax looks off

Answer (score 10):

When using mat-table, mat-row and mat-cell directives as tags rather than attributes on the html table, tr, td's the layout is flex, so you need to style the table accordingly.

The elements are layed-out sideways as mat-cell is "flex: row".

If you wrap the contents you want multi-line in a "div" that should do it:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <div>
    <div class="firstline">{{row.firstline}}</div>
    <div class="secondline">{{row.secondline}}</div>
  </div>
</mat-cell>
```